# HTML/CSS grid layout with different size boxes?

Tags: html, css, grid

I am trying to create a layout in HTML/CSS (as pictured).

I have tried using divs and ul/li's but the stacking doesn't work.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

[image: required layout]

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use table tag and colspan/rowspan attributes. However, this is a pretty old solution. 
The best thing you could do is use Bootstrap as Brad Werth suggested.
Another alternative is to create three classes of divs:

- One for squares
- One for horizontal rectangles
- One for the vertical rectangle

The you should create each div with its corresponding class. Remember that you would need to play with display attribute in order to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2):

if you really want to do this only in your own html/css (without Bootstrap),
your need to align the right block with the doubled height with float right and the other blocks using float left.

[Example - JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mj88Z/)

```
.block {
float:left;
}

.block1x2 {
float:right;
}
```